# Why am I having trouble settings my paths from eclipse to python when remote debugging?

Tags: python, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am remote debugging python on a raspberry pi from a windows 10 PC running Eclipse.  I am able to write and execute python scripts remotely.  SSH is working fine and I am able to start a debugging session without any problem.  However, when attempting to debug I keep getting the error

[image: error on raspberry pi]

I am attempting to set the remote path in the file simpleTest.py below.  This has worked previously.  However, for some reason the old settings appear to be getting confused with the attempt to set the remote path.

```
import pydevd
from pydevd_file_utils import setup_client_server_paths

MY_PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON = [ ('C:\\Users\\baff6\\workspace\\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\\192.168.1.20\\home\\pi\\', ''), ]
setup_client_server_paths(MY_PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON)
pydevd.settrace('192.168.1.10', port=5678)

a=1
print( a )
```

Previously I was remotely debugging a file called mpsTest2 on a different raspberry pi.  However, I am no longer working on this file even though Eclipse seems to be trying to find this file in the folder that contains the file that I am working on (in this case simpleTest2.py).

I have no idea where the references to this other file are but I presume they exist in some configuration setting in Eclipse.  However, I have looked everywhere and cannot find anything.

Any help in tracking down these settings would be much appreciated assuming I have not missed something very basic in the setup procedure I am following.

Best wishes, John

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have done this first but eventually found that uninstalling PyDev from Eclipse and reinstalling solved the problem.  This removed the old references and I was able to remotely debug without any problems.  I assume it is possible to achieve this end result without having to perform the uninstall/install but am not sure how to do this.